# creating a folder once user registred laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I would like to create a folder inside Storage folder in Laravel 5, once you register and pick your username, a folder with that user will be created for you.

If you created user : john5500 a folder inside Storage will be created with 'john5500' and will belong only to that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark, see the code below.

This code I use to create a new user in my database.

Information about ManagementCreateRequest $Request can be found via this URL.

[Laravel Controller Validation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#controller-validation)

In short I'm validating my input via Controller Validation in Laravel.
After the validation passes I get all the data from the validation in the variable $Request.

After that I create the user as below. After creating the user I send a redirect to the management page. This page contains an overview of all the users in the database.

```
public function store(ManagementCreateRequest $Request)
{
    // Create user
    Management::create($Request->all());

    // Return view
    return redirect('management')
        ->with('Success', 'User created.');
}
```

If I would to create a directory I would do it like this.

```
public function store(ManagementCreateRequest $Request)
{
    // Create user
    Management::create($Request->all());

    // Create directory
    File::MakeDirectory('/path/to/directory' . $Request->username);

    // Return view
    return redirect('management')
        ->with('Success', 'User created.');
}
```

Replace /path/to/directory with the actual path to your storage directory.
For example: Under CentOS my storage directory would be.

/var/www/Site Name/storage

Don't forget to replace 'Site Name' with the name of your Laravel site.

More detailed information about File:makeDirectory can be found via this link:

[Laravel Creating Directory](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/147/creating-a-directory)

Comment: Even when using Laravel 5 Framework you could still use those PHP commands like mkdir. But it's better to use the Storage or File Facade from Laravel itself. I totally forgot about those facades in Laravel when answering the question. Look at the reponse from Digitlimit or Fahad Hasan.

Comment: thank you very much for your efforts Mr Thomas, please take a look at this code:

http://pastebin.com/TfjrUjTJ

Comment: Can you comment the exact location of your storage folder, full path please. I will take look tomorrow morning at it and adjust the code you provided via pastebin.

Comment: thank you very much, im using homestead via vagrant box, my storage folder is : /storage

Comment: Try this code: http://pastebin.com/58iGTmV8
You need to create the directory before you go to the return part. Otherwise your code will never reach the part where you will create the directory. 
If you get an error message you should look into the path to your storage folder. I don't know Homestead that well but I think your path to your storage folder is not /storage.

Comment: This is the final line that worked:

File::MakeDirectory('/home/vagrant/Code/laravel/UserFolder/' . $data['username']);

Thank you so much for your help, indeed /storage is not the correct path

Comment: Great to hear Mark, could you accept the answer for me?

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.

Answer (score 1):

Lravel 5 comes with an excellent filesystem. You could simply do:

```
Storage::makeDirectory($directory);
```

See the documentation for more details: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/filesystem#basic-usage

Comment: where to add that line Sir?

Comment: Inside the controller where you are creating the user. i.e if you have a UserController.php, look inside the store() method. Create the directory once you have a new user created with a username. If you can post a pastebin link to your code, I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Laravel File Facade:

`File::makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0755, $recursive = false, $force = false);`

Ensure `storage` is writable

```
public function create(array $data)
{


            //return
            $user = User::create([
                    'name' => $data['name'],
                    'username'=>$data['username'],
                    'email' => $data['email'],
                    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),

            ]);


            \File::makeDirectory(storage_path($data['username']));

            return $user;


}
```

Comment: it still didn't work, no folder is created check the code:

http://pastebin.com/4gc8cSke

Comment: There is an error in your code. You did a `return` before attempting to create file. see edited answer